# Is the category of graded modules over a graded-commutative ring an AB5 category?

Tags: category-theory, modules, abelian-categories, limits-colimits, graded-rings

Is the category of $\mathbb{Z}$-graded modules over a graded-commutative ring an AB5 category? It is abelian, the subobjects of each object form a set, and it admits arbitrary coproducts. But I don't quite see how the 'filtered colimits of exact sequences are exact part' works.